# How to send, buffer, and receive Python objects between two python programs?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, buffer

I have the following scenario. Data (packets in this case) are received processed by a Python function in real-time as each datum streams by. So each datum is received and translated into a python object. There is a light-weight algorithm done on that object which returns an output (small dictionary). Then the object is discarded and the next one is handled. I have that program running.

Now, for each object the algorithm will produce a small dictionary of output data. This dictionary needs to be processed (also in real time) by a separate, second algorithm. I envision my code running two processes. I need to have the second process "listen" for the outputs of the first.

So how do I write this second algorithm in python so it can listen for and accept the data that is produced by the first? for a concrete example, suppose the first algorithm applies the timestamp, then passes to a buffer, and the second algorithm listens-- it grabs from the buffer and processes it. If there is nothing in the buffer, then as soon as something appears it processes it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html and https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html

Comment: Are you worried that running both transformations on a single core isn't fast enough? Because otherwise I'd just add the additional processing to the first program that produces the output dict. Adding IPC seems like overkill to me, and you're running into lots of potential problems that just can't happen if you have just one process doing both transformations.

Comment: @Pascal, so we might have the first process feed outputs to a buffer that is processed by a few different processes, so if i can do it for two i can do it for many is my thought. Also organization wise, it makes sense to not have them in one big pipeline. We'd like to make changes to and test them independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm aware this should be a comment, as it doesn't really answer your question but points to an alternative, but I can't fit this into a comment, so here it goes:

Building a pipeline out of processes looks like a clean solution, but there are some issues to think about:

#### Issues when using IPC / message queue solution

1. If you're not using shared memory, you have to pass your data as messages between your proceses. This means that every process has to deserialize it's input and serialize it's output just to do a simple transformation on the intermediate structure. You're losing a lot of efficiency just doing busywork serialization and deserialization.
2. Assuming you're designing your system in a waterfall model (first process passes data to the second one, which passes it to the third one, etc), if a single process somewhere in the chain dies, your whole pipeline breaks. So it's not necessarily more robust than a single-process pipeline (in fact, I'd expect it to break more often than the single-process solution)

#### Single process pipeline

You want your pipeline to be easily adjustable. So: Make sure you have an in-memory data format that is readable by every "transformator" (e.g. a dictionary with a few standardized attributes every transformator recognizes to know whether it can work on it or not.

Then write each transformator in it's own module (this helps making them easily (unit)testable on their own with very little additional scaffolding). Have your main application import all the transformator modules you need and register their transformators using a transformator  registry (basically a list of functions to call). In the main application, you read your input, turn it into the in-memory dictionary, run all the registered transformators on it sequentially and output the result.

This remains easily testable and adjustable because you can simply change which transformators you import and register.

You can even change the configuration (which transformators are run) while the process is running by storing the information which transformators to import and register in a file and if you want to adjust that while the process is running, you send it a SIGHUP (on Unix, anyway - on windows you will have to find another way to signal the process) which will cause it to re-read it's configuration file and adjust the list of transformators it runs on the data. That's not difficult to implement.

If you don't need the speed that running on multiple cores provides you with, this is more efficient, less likely to break and easier to reason about and support.

The basic idea would look a bit like this (without all the bells and whistles):

```
# this is transformator_a.py
def transform(data):
    return do_very_cool_stuff_to(data)

# this is transformator_b.py
import random
def transform(data):
    if can_i_handle_this(data):
        return do_some_more_cool_stuff_to(data)
    else:
        return data

def can_i_handle_this(data):
    # this is a very picky transformator - it's not always sure it
    # can handle the data
    i = random.randint(1, 5)
    return i == 2


# this is the main app
import transformator_a
import transformator_b

registered_transformators = [ transformator_a.transform, 
                              transformator_b.transform ]

while True:
    data = deserialize_data_unit_from_external_input_stream()
    for transform in registered_transformators:
        try:
           data = transform.transform(data)
        except SomeExcpetionsYouWantToHandle:
           # might not be fatal to the rest of the pipeline.
           # check whether data is still viable,
           # continue if so, exit process if not - or you might
           # just drop this data unit
           ensure_we_have_viable_data(data)
    serialize_data_unit_to_output_stream(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use different processes (as opposed to multiple functions in a single process), perhaps a messaging queue would work well for you? Whereby your first process would do whatever it does and put the results in a message queue, which your second process is listening to.

There are obviously a lot of options available but based on your description, this sounds like a reasonable approach.

Comment: i think a messaging queue sounds right. I've not used them. Can you suggest some link to an example?

Comment: You will need to choose the right type depending on how you want things to work. I have had success with using MQTT for this purpose, whereby a process can send messages to an MQTT topic, and one or more processes can listen to this topic, taking the appropriate action. VerneMQ is a great MQTT broker. If instead you want a system where only ONE process will access the message, you would want to instead consider a system where messages can be "ACK"-ed, such as RabbitMQ or SQS if you are on amazon.